# Do Latin novellas exist to help develop vocabulary for reading Vergil's Aeneid?

Tags: classical-latin

I'm taking a 4th semester Latin class in which we are jumping right into Vergil's *Aeneid,* said to be quite difficult. We were discussing the relatively recent phenomenon of 'novellas' being written in Latin, somewhat easier to read, and occasionally being  written with an aim of developing a particular facet of Latin comprehension. The question arose: Has any such novella been written specifically as an intermediary - perhaps essentially an abridged and simplified *Aeneid,* nevertheless in Latin - for students embarking on reading the *Aeneid*?

Answer (score 4):

Some of the early chapters in *Roma Aeterna,* Book II of Hans Ørberg's *Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata,* contain simplified prose versions of sections of the Aeneid. They're part of Ørberg's method of gradually introducing vocabulary and grammar entirely in Latin, with no translation to your native language, so you pick everything up from context.

I happen to be reading the first of these chapters right now. Here are a couple sentences, to give you an idea of the style and level of difficulty.

> Paulō post animī Trōiānōrum rē horrendā turbātī sunt: Dum Lāocoōn ad āram taurum immolat, subitō duo anguēs ingentēs ab īnsulā Tenedō per mare tranquillum ad lītus natant. Cum terram attigissent, capitibus ērēctīs oculīsque ārdentibus Trōiānōs perterritōs prōspiciunt.

In the margin, there is a picture of an *anguis*, and these notes:

> immolāre = sacrificiī causā occīdere
>
> at-tingere -tigisse -tāctum ( < ad+tangere) = tangere
>
> ē-rigere -rēxisse -rēctum = tollere

Those marginal notes are typical, and show how the book uses Latin to explain Latin.